# How to trigger KeyDown when there is a button on Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

The presence of a button on the Form1 window seems to prevent the KeyDown event from being triggered. What should I do to make that the button doesn't prevent KeyDown to be triggered?

[**Here is a picture of my Form1.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPZuh.png) `timer` is Enabled.

---

**Code :**

```
    Brush brush;

    int dimensions;
    Point point;
    Size size;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    Color color;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DefineRectangle();
        brush = Brushes.Black

        color = BackColor;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            brush = Brushes.Green;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            brush = Brushes.Yellow;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            brush = Brushes.Orange;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            brush = Brushes.Red;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DefineRectangle();
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void DefineRectangle()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        dimensions = random.Next(5, 51) * 2;

        point = new Point
            (
                random.Next(284 / dimensions) * dimensions,
                random.Next(260 / dimensions) * dimensions
            );

        size = new Size(dimensions, dimensions);

        rectangle = new Rectangle(point, size);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Blue;
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = color;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: you'll need to set KeyPreview property of your form to true

Comment: Being an international forum, you are supposed to write your questions/responses in English only so that people here can understand you

Comment: Sorry, I'm sleepy. I just did it but it absolutely does not work. - @kashi_rock

Comment: Why do you think it's the button's fault?

Answer (score 1):

In your Form, you may try to override ProcessCmdKey:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message message, Keys keyData)
{
     if (keyData == Keys.Down)
          return true;

     return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref message, keyData);
}
```

Before doing this method, set the `KeyPreview property = true` for the form

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do an easy workaround. Just add the keydown handler you specified to the handlers of the two buttons aswell. This should make it work and you can continue with your homework.

Just select them in the designer and in the properties menu you can bind the same method to their keyDown event.

Proper solution would be to do this in the constructor

```
    public Form1() : base()
    {        

        // Set KeyPreview object to true to allow the form to process 
        // the key before the control with focus processes it.
        this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```

Comment: Did you also try the first option i mentioned? Adding the Form1_KeyDown event handler to the same events of button1 and button2?

Comment: I managed with KeyPreview, thank you. But there is always a problem that I do not understand. *When launching the WinForm application, a visible button always has focus. Why is it so? How to disable this behavior?* **Maybe I will ask this in a new question.**

Comment: The one with the minimum tab index automatically gets the focus (assuming the TabStop property is set to true). Just set the tab indices appropriately.

By the way, Visual Studio provides a way to easily set tab indices by just clicking on the controls in the order you want. You can activate this feature by choosing "Tab Order" option in the "View" menu when you are in the form design view.

You can also manually give the focus to a control by calling its Select method when the form loads.

Comment: It works well ! But... I set `TabStop` of my `button1` to false. Then I run the application. Now the button appears but doesn't have focus, which is what I wanted ! But when I click on the button, it takes the focus, which stays on it ; while I would like that after clicking, it loses focus. So I tried to do in the click event `button1.Parent.Select ();` or `button1.Parent.Focus();` but the focus is always on the button. (I also noticed that Form1 does not have a `TabIndex` in its properties. Maybe that's the reason.) Do you know how to remove the focus from the button after clicking it ?

Comment: All you got to do is add this line to the end of the key's Click event:
this.Focus(); --> this contains the reference to the parent aka the form